# Finding Multicollinearity of Categorical and Numerical variables

Tags: regression, correlation, multicollinearity

I have a data set with 15 categorical variables of which 13 are nominal and two are ordinal variables, along with these I have 10 numerical variables.

I am using R to build a multiple regression model. For numerical variables I have used `Corr()` from R to find the correlation between numerical variables, however I would like to know if there is a way to find correlation between all Categorical variables at once? Also how would I find the correlation between categorical and numerical variables. Certainly I can not do this individually as there are many variables.

I have dummified the categorical variables to find the correlation between numerical and categorical variables but I believe that dummification doesn't​ help in finding the correct correlation.

Comment: Perhaps the quickest and simplest way to assess multivariate linear relationships among all the variables is to regress any variable (pick a constant or choose random numbers) against them: the software automatically performs this evaluation and can emit diagnostics to help you understand it.  If you literally want to assess *correlation,* in the sense of any bivariate correlation coefficient, then why not just compute and review the correlation matrix? What do you actually mean by "the correct correlation" in that case?

Comment: By correct correlation I mean that as we dummify categorical variables, they get split in to multiple variables (n-1) and they won't capture the correlation properly because of the splitting.

Comment: There is such a thing as the *generalized* variance inflation factor (see: [Fox & Monette, 1992](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290467)) that can work for categorical variables as well as continuous ones. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, while applying VIF I get an error that says there are many near zero variance variables, and VIF can't be applied. Is it always necessary to dummify categorical variables for applying VIF? Or can we simply apply VIF on factor variables without dummification?

Comment: Can you try converting your categorical variables to ordinals with numerical relation of equidistance? Then find collinearity and eliminate collinear ones. Of what is left convert them back to categorical. Then dummify and regress.

Comment: @Sunny, as my data has few variables with levels up to 500, even after converting them to numerical of equal distance. I get an error that says there are many near zero or non zero variance variables in the data